# Sharepoint 2007 people picker expand group to individuals

Tags: sharepoint, peoplepicker

I am using a Sharepoint 2007 customized people picker control for a webpart (`PickerDialog`, `CustomQueryControl`, `EntityEditorWithPicker`).  The control was working fine but the Sharepoint SP3 was applied and the control no longer allows me to expand a group entity to individual entities during a postback in the text box after the item is selected from the people picker dialog box.

I have tried `OnValueChangedClientScript` but can't access the text box. I would like it to expand a group entity to individual entities the way it used to before the SP3 was applied.  I understand that SP2 was more forgiving than SP3, but is there a code workaround?

**Additional information:**  I assigned the new values to `CommaSeparatedAccounts` after the Dialog Box exits and a postback occurred, then we could update the people picker text box with new values and then set the `CommaSeparatedAccounts`, SP3 no longer has the postback and will not change values in the Textbox by setting the `CommaSeparatedAccounts`.